# reserve space for dynamically appearing text

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have some text that shows up conditionally.
When the text is showing, it pushes down the rest of the page.

What is the correct way to reserve the space of the text even when it's not shown so that I avoid the push downs?

I want to avoid using absolute positions and giving pre-fixed height to a container.

Snippet is attached.
Just click the button and see the green box gets pushed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "hello",
    push:false
  }
});
```

```css
button{
  display:block;
}
#push-down{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:green;
}

p{
  font-size:30px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="push=!push">click me to push</button>
  <p v-show="push">{{message}}</p>
  <div id="push-down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the only way to do that would be to set a min-height for the reserved space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by setting the CSS property `visibility` on the element.

Setting this property to `hidden` will hide the element from view whilst maintaining the space it would use when visible.  You can make it visible by setting `visibility` to `visible` [Check out the MDN docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

Comment: `<p :style="{visibility: (push) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">{{message}}</p>` is how you could do this in vue

Comment: @thanksd: Thanks, for clarifying the actual VueJS syntax

Comment: `<p :style="{opacity: +push}">{{message}}</p>` Opacity works too and would be a little less verbose in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you know the element's height you could just wrap it on a div with defined height.

Comment: " avoid using absolute positions and giving pre-fixed height" he said.